# What does the string.find(substring) function returns when substring is just a newline?

Tags: c++, string

I have a program which is used to check for a sub-string into a string.
Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
int main()
{
  std::string str, substr;
  std::cout<<"\n Enter a string : ";
  std::getline(std::cin, str);
  std::cout<<"\n Enter a possible substring of the string : ";
  std::getline(std::cin, substr);
  std::size_t position = str.find(substr);
  if(position != std::string::npos)
    std::cout<<substr<<" was found at position "<<position<<std::endl;
  else
    std::cout<<"\n The substring you entered wasn't found \n";
  return 0;
}
```

I have one input for which it is not giving correct output.
Example:

```
 Enter a string : Stackoverflow         

 Enter a possible substring of the string : 
 was found at position 0
```

While entering the substring I just press the enter key. So the output should be `The substring you entered wasn't found`.
What does the find() method is returning in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing enter on an empty input does not put a newline into the string.  `std::getline` consumes the newline so all you have in an empty string for the sub-string.

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) the function [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

> an empty substring is found at pos if and only if `pos <= size()`

In your example `pos` is `0` as you use the default parameter so `find` returns `0`.  Since `find` returned `0` you satisfy the if condition.  To prevent this you can check for an empty string like

```
if(position != std::string::npos && !substr.empty())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `std::getline()` function does not include the linefeed in the returned string, so if you just press enter it will return an empty string. The empty string is in any string.

Add code to verify that the `substr` is non-empty, before doing the search.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by entering a new line you are essentially searching for nothing, i.e. `""`. `""` is found immediately (at the start of the string), so `position` is `0`, not `-1` (`std::string::npos`). The newline character is not retrieved by std::getline.

Comment: Just a bit of clarification: the newline **is** retrieved by `std::getline` in that it is no longer in the input stream. But it does not get put into the target string, which is why, as this answer says, the resulting string is empty.

Answer (score 0):

According to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) - .find() function returns

> The position of the first character of the first match.

As you are pressing enter button, std::getline() takes an empty string and an empty string is common in every string. So it returns the position, 0 (the start of the string).

You can check if the substring is empty or not to avoid this situation.